# Modify a matrix in ocaml

Tags: matrix, ocaml

I want to write a function that is modify every elements inside a matrix. 
But I have some problem when compiling.

> Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.

I think because all function in ocaml need to return to a value or unit, so if I implement two tasks inside one function, it is not acceptable.
Please help me to fix it.

```
let nomalize_matrix d a x = 
 for i = 1 to d do 
      for j = 1 to d do
          let n = i*j in
          x.(i)(j) = sprintf "%s_%d" a n
      done
  done;
x;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an expression the `=` operator in OCaml is a comparison operator that tests for equality. To assign to an array, use the `<-` operator.

The compiler is complaining because your expression has type `bool` (i.e., the result of the comparison). The expression in a `for` should have type `unit` since its return value is ignored. And indeed, the `<-` operator returns `()`, the unit value.

To access an element of a two-dimensional array, the syntax looks like: `x.(i).(j)`. Note the extra dot, not present in your code.

There is no problem in general with doing two things in a function. You can separate two expressions with `;` if the first has type `unit`. The result is the value of the second expression. Your code is OK in this respect.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right, this operator is a problem. It was fixed and ran well.

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful to do not use the operator "=" when you set one item from an array and use the operator "<-" instead so in your code, you have this :

```
let nomalize_matrix d a x = 
 for i = 1 to d do 
      for j = 1 to d do
          let n = i*j in
          x.(i)(j) <- sprintf "%s_%d" a n
      done
  done;
x;;
```